# How to make UpdatePanel to do Update after custom Event?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel

I'm setting `UpdatePanel1.UpdateMode = UpdatePanelUpdateMode.Conditional;` to make manual updates but it doesn't work for some custom events, when I have some event alike here:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    discovery.FindAlreadyRegisteredServices();
    discovery.discoveryClient.FindCompleted += FoundEvent;

protected void FoundEvent(object sender, FindCompletedEventArgs e) {
    Label1.Text = (discovery.endpoints.Count > 0) ? discovery.endpoints[0].Address.ToString() : "nothing";
    UpdatePanel1.Update();
    }
```

My project is failing with:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.ServiceModel.Internals.dll

Additional information: The Update method can only be called on UpdatePanel with ID 'UpdatePanel1' before Render.
```

even if I set `ChildrenAsTriggers` or not. Error message is not clear for me and I can't understand what should I do to process update right after I process my event?

addition:

aspx:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="Button1_Click" />
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
        <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server">
        </asp:ListView>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: You get this exception when button1 is clicked?

Comment: Please share the aspx code as well.

Comment: I get exception on UpdatePanel1.Update();

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you should change your markup like this

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    ....
```

You should set `UpdateMode="Conditional"` in your markup itself

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    discovery.FindAlreadyRegisteredServices();
    discovery.discoveryClient.FindCompleted += FoundEvent;
  // Try to call the update method after calling the custom even but in the click event of the button. Ensure you update the Trigger accordingly in the update panel
 **UpdatePanel1.Update();**
}

protected void FoundEvent(object sender, FindCompletedEventArgs e) {
    Label1.Text = (discovery.endpoints.Count > 0) ? discovery.endpoints[0].Address.ToString() : "nothing";
       }
```

Try to add AsyncPostBackTrigger to the update panel with update mode as conditional

Although you are doing same thing explicitly.

```
<Triggers>  
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Button1" EventName="Click" />  
            </Triggers>
```

*Just to check if there is any other issue, you can set the updateMode property of the update panel to "Always"*

Comment: I used to set ChildrenAsTriggers for button but I don't need button exactly I need my custom Event.

Comment: Put your label inside the update panel with update mode as **"always"** and then call the **update** method of the update panel in your custome event. No need to use ChildrenAsTriggers property. It is intended to be used only when the UpdateMode property is set to Conditional. If this works, You can later change the UpdateMode as conditional for performance reasons.

Comment: The Update method can only be called on UpdatePanel with ID 'UpdatePanel1' when UpdateMode is set to Conditional.